# Blenderで作成したモデルをVRで触って回転させたい

Tags: unity3d, blender

Blenderで、ある回転軸を中心に回転するようなモデル(手で回す鉛筆削り器のように、回転する部分と固定部分で構成)を作り、それをUnityのVRモードで回転部を掴み回転させたいのですが、
モデル作成時には回転部と固定部は別個に作る必要があるのでしょうか。
それとも、両方を一体で作り、一部分のみ回転できるよう何らかの処理が必要なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

触って回転させるという処理が経験がないので分からないのですが、オブジェクトが分かれていた方がいいでしょう。
別個=別々のfbxにエクスポートでもいいですし、別々のオブジェクトで一つのfbxにエクスポートでもOKです。後者の場合、unity側でもオブジェクトが２つできます。
これを、一つにしてしまうと、普通には回転させられません。

Comment: 別々につくってみます。ありがとうございます。